# google account disable security check

Tags: gmail, automated-tests, integration-testing, ui-automation

For google account used in automation testing script.

Is there a way I can turn off the security check when login from different computer?

Or does google provide a special account for testing that can be configured to disable security check?

Comment: Do you mean Google 2 step verification?

Comment: So even the 2 step verification is off when you login from a location or computer that seems suspective to google, it will trigger the verification.